# Best way to graph some data

Tags: ios, graph

I am wanting to display a line graph with details containing wind speed/gust/lulls etc for out local club paragliding app I am making.  wondering what the best way to go about it with is?

The current data is just on the web so something similar that I can pinch zoom maybe:
http://www.acthpa.org/wind/

Willy weather has an awesome app that display very nicely, anyone know what they might have used to make it so? the web is very similar to their iPHone app:
http://wind.willyweather.com.au/vic/western-district/wild-dog-beach.html

Answer (score 0):

after looking around at various 3rd party's, i'm using Core Plot :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've put together a really simple class for displaying line graphs, check it out at https://github.com/johnyorke/JYGraphViewController

Perhaps rotate the phone for the graph view then swipe up and down to go between the different metrics you wish to show?

Answer (score -1):

There are various third party graphing libraries for iOS. I looked into CorePlot a while back, but did not end up needing it. It looked full-featured, although I've seen posts that it is rather complex and involved to use.

Comment: currently mucking around with Core Plot, just wondering if there a better options..  Free is the key.. haha